# Amazon's CreateSpace doesn't scale my book

Tags: publishing

I want to sell a printed book on Amazon but I simply can't pass the "Scale" step in the Previewer.

I've uploaded the book and the cover (PDF files), then I enter into the Previewer and I get this error window:

> You chose 6.14" x 9.21" but your file is 6.0833" x 9.0833"
>
> You have one option(s) to auto-fix your file
>
> **Page Scaling**
>
> Each page of your uploaded file will be scaled to match your book trim
>   size. Your page count will not change. If the trim size is a
>   different shape than your file, additional blank space may appear at
>   the bottom of each page.

I click the "Page Scaling" button (a square) but (after waiting for "Loading..") nothing happens. My book remains unscaled, and it doesn't allow me to push the button "Approve" (at the bottom of the page).

I've also got an "Auto-fix Trim Size" button at the bottom left of the page, and when I push it, it opens again the window with the error above. Again I click on the "Page Scaling" and again, nothing happens.

The problem is that I can't publish my book. When I exit the PrintPreviewer, I get this message "It looks like you've made some changes to your manuscript or book cover. Please preview and approve these changes before continuing." And when I push "Save and Continue", I get the error "Please preview and approve your book" so I'm stuck at "Paperback Content".

I've sent a message to Amazon (Help - Contact Us) and I got no answer. Is there any other way I can scale my book so Amazon will accept it?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. We are not CreateSpace troubleshooting. Please contact Amazon for help with Amazon products.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, do you think it's a good idea to delete this question and to ask again at webapps? Awesome name, by the way :)

Comment: Deleting the question is up to you. You can arrange to talk to an Amazon CSR on the phone, so I recommend you try that rather than posting on another Stack Exchange site which is still not Amazon. (and thanks! My username gets noticed about once a year. ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use createspace. I suggest that you first change your print size to 6inch by 9inch and then you shouldn't have any trouble. But createspace does have a very useful forum where you can ask stuff or just go onto the kdp community.